# Enable reviews in single product page not working

Tags: woocommerce, twig, review

I'm trying to show reviews on a website using wordpress, woocommerce and Twig but I don't have the checking box to enable reviews. I'm lost and don't know why I don't have the option to enable reviews. I guess it comes from the plugin.

Thanks for your help!

[See capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAlcw.png)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It's under the advanced tab. It's a builtin-in WooCommerce feature.